# Zbar camera view border color

Tags: iphone, zbar-sdk

I'm using Zbar qr and bar code recongnition tool in my app.

I've recompiled the framework to support iPad screen size as well, but now I get is the redish and bluish rectangle around camera view.

Any ideas how get reed of it ?

[image: blue lines on the sides, and red on top and bottom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've fixed this in the sources of Zbar, recompiled and used my own build of library...

Comment: Do you remember how you did it? I am having the same problem, and can't find the reason in the source code. (I am compiling a version of the Zbar archive)

Comment: Ah sorry, can't remember right now, the question was dated to 2011.

Comment: But try to find some lines in the sources related to `UIColor`

Comment: Found it! For future references: In the project's build settings, search for the preprocessing macros. The Debug setting says `DEBUG_OBJC=1`. You need to set it to `NDEBUG=1` to get rid of the Debug options (printing debug info, border around readerview, etc)

Comment: Yeah, might be that what I've changed as well, sorry couldn't remember exactly.

Comment: No problem, thanks for giving me the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `reader.cameraOverlayView = nil` ?

I guess you have already read the documentation, but if you did not, here is the link : [ZBar documentation](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/custom.html)

Comment: I've created cameraOverlayView, it doesn't make sense to assign nil to it, as the default camera layout does not meet UI requirements in my case...